# Enable bootstrap button using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Collegues, i have а bootstrap button on my html page:

```
.....
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
...

    <div class="accept-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning disabled" onclick="acceptPmt()">Accept</button>
    </div>
```

and i have JavaScript function which should activate (enable) it:

```
    function activateAcceptButton() {
        const accBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('accept-btn');
        //accBtn[0].disabled = false;
        //accBtn[0].classList.add('accept-btn-vis');
        //accBtn[0].setProperty("disabled", false);
        //accBtn[0].style.setProperty("enable", true);

        accBtn[0].removeClass('disabled');
    }
```

When the function is called nothing changes. Could you please help me with button activation? How do i need to change js function?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using incorrect selector. `document.getElementsByClassName('accept-btn')` will select the `div`. Instead, you can directly refer to the button using the descendant selector (`>`). Your could use: `document.querySelector('.accept-btn > button')`.

Also, instead of `.removeClass()`, you could use `.classList.remove()` on the button.

```js
function activateAcceptButton() {
  const accBtn = document.querySelector('.accept-btn > button');
  accBtn.classList.remove('disabled');
}

function acceptPmt() {}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> ...

<div class="accept-btn">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning disabled" onclick="acceptPmt()">Accept</button>
</div>


<button onclick="activateAcceptButton()">Activate</button>
```

Alternatively, you can keep the selector as it is, and select the first child of the `div`. The commented statements in that function will also require being modified accordingly:

```js
function activateAcceptButton() {
  const accBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('accept-btn');
  accBtn[0].children[0].classList.remove('disabled');
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> ...

<div class="accept-btn">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning disabled" onclick="acceptPmt()">Accept</button>
</div>


<button onclick="activateAcceptButton()">Activate</button>
```

Comment: Why shouldn’t `removeClass` be used?

Comment: @ScottHunter Is it a native method on an element? I'm aware of jQuery API for `removeClass`. But the code here doesn't use jQuery.

Comment: Fisrt approach works fine. Thank you. But the second returns: `homepage.js:98 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at activateAcceptButton (homepage.js:98)
    at buildTree (homepage.js:70)
    at response.json.then.json (homepage.js:25)
    at <anonymous>`

Comment: @May12 Fixed the second one. I missed that `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of nodes, rather than a single node. So referring to the `div` using `accBtn[0]` should work.

Comment: @Nisarg Shah, yes, now every case works. The second variant is more clear for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Using querySelector for bootstrap DOM in javascript**

```js
function activateAcceptButton() {
  /* selector class accept-btn of class btn,btn-warning,disable */
//  const accBtn = document.querySelector(".accept-btn [id=accept][type=button].btn.btn-warning.disabled");
  
  /* short */
  const accBtn = document.querySelector(".accept-btn [id=accept]");

  if (accBtn.classList) { 
    accBtn.classList.remove("disabled");
  } else {
    accBtn.className = accBtn.className.replace(/\bmydisabled\b/g, ""); // For IE9 and earlier
  }  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="accept-btn">
  <button id="accept" type="button" class="btn btn-warning disabled" onclick="acceptPmt()">Accept</button>
</div>
    
<button onclick="activateAcceptButton()">Active</button>
```

[CSS Selector for using querySelector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)